# How to use "internal" packages?

Tags: go

I try understand how to organize go code using "internal" packages. Let me show what the structure I have:

```
project/
  internal/
    foo/
      foo.go # package foo
    bar/
      bar.go # package bar
  main.go

# here is the code from main.go
package main

import (
  "project/internal/foo"
  "project/internal/bar"
)
```

`project/` is outside from GOPATH tree. Whatever path I try to import from `main.go` nothing works, the only case working fine is `import "./internal/foo|bar"`. I think I do something wrong or get "internal" package idea wrong in general. Could anybody make things clearer, please?

**UPDATE**

The example above is correct the only what I need was to place `project/` folder under `$GOPATH/src`. So the thing is import path like the `project/internal/foo|bar` is workable if we only import it from `project/` subtree and not from the outside.

Comment: You can't import packages that are not in `$GOPATH/src`. Try creating a `project/baz` package, you won't be able to import it either. Put all your projects into GOPATH.

Comment: Note that these comments have been outdated by [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) -- they allow users to build go src outside of GOPATH.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The packages have to be located in your `$GOPATH` in order to be imported. The example you gave with `import "./internal/foo|bar"` works because it does a local-import. `internal` only makes it so code that doesn't share a common root directory to your `internal` directory can't import the packages within `internal`.

If you put all this in your gopath then tried to import from a different location like `OuterFolder/project2/main.go` where `OuterFolder` contains both `project` and `project2` then `import "../../project/internal/foo"` would fail. It would also fail as `import "foo"` or any other way your tried due to not satisfying this condition;

> An import of a path containing the element “internal” is disallowed if
>   the importing code is outside the tree rooted at the parent of the
>   “internal” directory.

Now if you had the path `$GOPATH/src/project` then you could do `import "foo"` and `import "bar"` from within `$GOPATH/src/project/main.go` and the import would succeed. Things that are not contained underneath `project` however would not be able to import `foo` or `bar`.

Answer (score 59):

With modules introduction in Go v1.11 and above you don't have to specify your project path in $GOPATH/src

You need to tell Go about where each module located by creating go.mod file. Please refer to `go help mod` documentation.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
project
|   go.mod
|   main.go
|
\---internal
    +---bar
    |       bar.go
    |       go.mod
    |
    \---foo
            foo.go
            go.mod
```

project/internal/bar/go.mod

```
module bar

go 1.14
```

project/internal/bar/bar.go

```
package bar

import "fmt"

//Bar prints "Hello from Bar"
func Bar() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Bar")
}
```

project/internal/foo/go.mod

```
module foo

go 1.14
```

project/internal/foo/foo.go

```
package foo

import "fmt"

//Foo prints "Hello from Foo"
func Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Foo")
}
```

project/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "internal/bar"
    "internal/foo"
)

func main() {
    bar.Bar()
    foo.Foo()
}
```

Now the most important module
project/go.mod

```
module project

go 1.14


require internal/bar v1.0.0
replace internal/bar => ./internal/bar
require internal/foo v1.0.0
replace internal/foo => ./internal/foo
```

Couple things here:

1. You can have any name in require. You can have project/internal/bar if you wish. What Go think it is URL address for the package, so it will try to pull it from web and give you error

```
go: internal/bar@v1.0.0: malformed module path "internal/bar": missing dot in first path element
```

That is the reason why you need to have `replace` where you tell Go where to find it, and that is the key!

```
replace internal/bar => ./internal/bar
```

2. The version doesn't matter in this case. You can have v0.0.0 and it will work.

Now, when you execute your code you will have

```
Hello from Bar
Hello from Foo
```

[Here is GitHub link for this code example](https://github.com/vlad-bezden/gonestedmodules)

Comment: Why would one use a module for each package? I mean, I get why you wouldn't use a single `go.mod` for the entire project, after all, you want the `internal` folder to not be accessible for projects referencing your module (don't quote me on this, I think internal won't be accessible but I haven't tested). But having a different `go.mod` file for `foo` and `bar` seems weird, why shouldn't you use a single `go.mod` file for the entire `internal` directory?

Comment: As far as I know, nowadays you only need a go.mod at the root of the application and none on the subpackages. But hey, thanks for the replace keyword tip, I had been going nuts with "outside GOROOT" errors because of not knowing about it.

Answer (score 25):

below way is more scalable, especially when you plan to build multiple binaries

```
github.com/servi-io/api
├── cmd/
│   ├── servi/
│   │   ├── cmdupdate/
│   │   ├── cmdquery/
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── servid/
│       ├── routes/
│       │   └── handlers/
│       ├── tests/
│       └── main.go
├── internal/
│   ├── attachments/
│   ├── locations/
│   ├── orders/
│   │   ├── customers/
│   │   ├── items/
│   │   ├── tags/
│   │   └── orders.go
│   ├── registrations/
│   └── platform/
│       ├── crypto/
│       ├── mongo/
│       └── json/
```

The folders inside `cmd/` represents the number of binaries you want to build.

[for more](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/02/package-oriented-design.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also to check: When you are using your externally imported object types:  **make sure you are prefixing them with the namespace they're in.**  As a golang newbie, I didn't know I had to do that, and was wondering why is VS Code just removing my import (for not being used) when I saved.   It's because I had to **prefix the imported object with the namespace name:**

```
Example:
import (
    "myInternalPackageName"  // works fine as long as you follow all instructions in this thread
)

//Usage in code: 
myInternalPackageName.TheStructName   // prefix it, or it won't work.
```

If you don't put the namespace prefix before the object/struct name, VS code just removes your import for being unused, and then you still have the error:  "Can't find TheStructName"...   That was very confusing, and I had to do a build without VS code through the command line to understand that.

**The point is:  I had to specify the package prefix when actually using the struct from that internal package.**

If you don't want to use the qualifier prefix when using imported objects, use:

```
import . "thePath"    // Can use contents without prefixing.
```

Reference: [What does the '.' (dot or period) in a Go import statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478962/what-does-the-dot-or-period-in-a-go-import-statement-do)