# Go: repository layout for microservices with shared code

Tags: go, microservices, monorepo

We recently started using Go for new microservices. Each microservice is a Go module, and we manage them as a monorepo:

```
/
  services/
    s1/
      go.mod
      main.go
    s2/
      go.mod
      main.go
```

This works fine, but now we need to share some code between `s1` and `s2` - some structs used by both services, a function that uploads to S3, etc.

What's the correct way of managing this situation? Ideally, I'd have a `common` directory at the repo root (sibling of `services`) and put the common code there - but how will Go take the code from there when compiling `s1` and `s2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're asking is really just a variation of "[How to structure Go application to produce multiple binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904560/how-to-structure-go-application-to-produce-multiple-binaries)".

You would move your `go.mod` to the top-level directory rename, so that you have this layout:

```
.
├── common
│   └── common.go
├── go.mod
└── services
    ├── s1
    │   └── main.go
    └── s2
        └── main.go
```

And a `go.mod` that starts with something like:

```
module mymodule
```

If `common/common.go` looks like this:

```
package common

func CommonFunction() string {
    return "This is a common function"
}
```

Then in `services/s1/main.go`, you can import the `common` module:

```
package main

import (
        "mymodule/common"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        res := common.CommonFunction()
        fmt.Println(res)
}
```

And you would build the `s1` service like this:

```
go build ./services/s1
```

Building `s2` would be similar:

```
go build ./services/s2
```

You would typically have a top-level `Makefile` to automate building of the multiple services.

Comment: This looks great, thanks. I will give it a try and if it does what I need I'll accept.

Comment: What if `s1` needs dependencies that are not needed by `s2`? A single `go.mod` means they will both get it, and the docker image will be larger.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I think the Go linker is smart enough to not include unnecessary dependencies in the compiled binary. I'm not 100% sure, so if your existing project has those characteristics, try this structure and see what impact it has on the final sizes.