# Using logger/configs in multi packages best practice for Golang productive

Tags: go, dependency-injection, interface

I've the following project structure:

```
myGithubProject/
    |---- cmd
      |----- command
        |----- hello.go
    |---- internal
        |----- template
           |----- template.go
        |----- log
          |----- logger.go
    main.go
```

The `log` and the `template` are on the same level  (under internal package)
In `logger.go` Im using `logrus` as logger with some config sand I want to use the `logger.go`  object inside the `template` package.
How should I do that in a clean way ?

Currently I use it with `import logger` inside my `template.go` file,

And under `internal` package I’ve `6` more `packages` which needs this `logger`. and each of them is depend on it.
(On the `log` package), is there a nice in go to handle it ?

**update:**

in case I've more things that I need to pass (like logger)  what will be the approach/ pattern here ? maybe using `dependency injection` ? `interface` ? other clean approach...

I need some **best practice full example** how can I use `logger` inside the `hello.go` file and also in `template.go`.

this is my project

```
cliProject/main.go

package main

import (
    "cliProject/cmd"
    "cliProject/internal/logs"
)

func main() {
    cmd.Execute()
    logs.Logger.Error("starting")
}


**cliProject/cmd/root.go**

package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "cliProject",
    Short: "A brief description of your application",
}

func Execute() {
    if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

**cliProject/cmd/serve.go**

package cmd

import (
    "cliProject/internal/logs"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

// serveCmd represents the serve command
var serveCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "serve",
    Short: "A brief description of your command",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Println("serve called")
        startServe()
        stoppingServe()
    },
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(serveCmd)
    serveCmd.Flags().BoolP("toggle", "t", false, "Help message for toggle")
}

func startServe() {
    logs.Logger.Error("starting from function serve")
}

func stoppingServe() {
    logs.Logger.Error("stoping from function serve")
}


**cliProject/cmd/start.go**

package cmd

import (
    "cliProject/internal/logs"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

// startCmd represents the start command
var startCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "start",
    Short: "Start command",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        // Print the logs via logger from internal
        logs.Logger.Println("start called inline")
        // example of many functions which should use the logs...
        start()
        stopping()

    },
}

func init() {
    logs.NewLogger()
    rootCmd.AddCommand(startCmd)
    startCmd.Flags().BoolP("toggle", "t", false, "Help message for toggle")
}

func start() {
    logs.Logger.Error("starting from function start")
}

func stopping() {
    logs.Logger.Error("stoping from function start")
}


**cliProject/internal/logs/logger.go**

package logs

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter"
    "os"
)

var Logger *logrus.Logger

func NewLogger() *logrus.Logger {

    var level logrus.Level
    level = LogLevel("info")
    logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stdout,
        Level: level,
        Formatter: &prefixed.TextFormatter{
            DisableColors:   true,
            TimestampFormat: "2009-06-03 11:04:075",
        },
    }
    Logger = logger
    return Logger
}

func LogLevel(lvl string) logrus.Level {
    switch lvl {
    case "info":
        return logrus.InfoLevel
    case "error":
        return logrus.ErrorLevel
    default:
        panic("Not supported")
    }
}
```

this is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> And under internal package I’ve 6 more packages which needs this logger. and each of them is depend on it. (On the log package), is there a nice in go to handle it ?

A good general principle would be to **respect the application's choice** (whether to log or not) instead of setting policy.

1. Let Go pkgs in your `internal` directory be *support packages* that

   - will only return `error` in case of problems
   - won't log (console or otherwise)
   - won't `panic`
2. Let your application (packages in your `cmd` directory) decide what the appropriate behavior in case of an error (log / graceful shutdown / recover to 100% integrity)

This would streamline development by having logging at a particular layer only. Note: remember to give the application give enough context to determine action

**internal/process/process.go**

```
package process

import (
    "errors"
)

var (
    ErrNotFound = errors.New("Not Found")
    ErrConnFail = errors.New("Connection Failed")
)

// function Process is a dummy function that returns error for certain arguments received
func Process(i int) error {
    switch i {
    case 6:
        return ErrNotFound
    case 7:
        return ErrConnFail
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

**cmd/servi/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    p "../../internal/process"
)

func main() {
    // sample: generic logging on any failure
    err := p.Process(6)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("FAIL", err)
    }

    // sample: this application decides how to handle error based on context
    err = p.Process(7)
    if err != nil {
        switch err {
        case p.ErrNotFound:
            log.Println("DOESN'T EXIST. TRY ANOTHER")
        case p.ErrConnFail:
            log.Println("UNABLE TO CONNECT; WILL RETRY LATER")
        }
    }
}
```

> in case I've more things that I need to pass (like logger) what will be the approach/ pattern here

Dependency injection is always a good first choice. Consider others only when the simplest implementation is insufficient.

The code below 'wires' the `template` and `logger` packages together using dependency injection and first-class function passing.

**internal/logs/logger.go**

```
package logger

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter"
    "os"
)

var Logger *logrus.Logger

func NewLogger() *logrus.Logger {

    var level logrus.Level
    level = LogLevel("info")
    logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stdout,
        Level: level,
        Formatter: &prefixed.TextFormatter{
            DisableColors:   true,
            TimestampFormat: "2009-06-03 11:04:075",
        },
    }
    Logger = logger
    return Logger
}

func LogLevel(lvl string) logrus.Level {
    switch lvl {
    case "info":
        return logrus.InfoLevel
    case "error":
        return logrus.ErrorLevel
    default:
        panic("Not supported")
    }
}
```

**internal/template/template.go**

```
package template

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type Template struct {
    Name   string
    logger *logrus.Logger
}

// factory function New accepts a logging function and some data
func New(logger *logrus.Logger, data string) *Template {
    return &Template{data, logger}
}

// dummy function DoSomething should do something and log using the given logger
func (t *Template) DoSomething() {
    t.logger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s", t.Name, "did something"))
}
```

**cmd/servi2/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "../../internal/logs"
    "../../internal/template"
)

func main() {
    // wire our template and logger together
    loggingFunc := logger.NewLogger()

    t := template.New(loggingFunc, "Penguin Template")

    // use the stuff we've set up
    t.DoSomething()
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: Hi, thanks. for your first example . if I want to use logger inside `cmd` package from the internal , how would you do it ?

Comment: in addition please see my update with the logger file

Comment: A good practice would be to keep `logger` and `template` separate, and "wire them together" at the application level. It keeps `logger` and `template` separate (no dependencies) and independently testable I've updated the 2nd part with a more full example of this.

Comment: Just to verify :) are you recommended on the DI ? your last example ?

Comment: I've checked your example and it works :) the problem is now I want to use my code (see the code in the question) and Im running into problems...can you try please to change in your example the simple-logger to my file?

Comment: btw , I read this article , its not better to use interface? https://appliedgo.net/di/

Comment: _can you try please to change in your example the simple-logger to my file_ -> I've tried but there are a few issues. `getLogLevel()` not defined and there's those ellipsis `...` also. Can you edit to share your full file?

Comment: _btw , I read this article , its not better to use interface?_ -> Hmmm, I've read that article and I'm not sure its the explanation I would use. Some of the items also seem non-idiomatic to Go (ie `type PoemStorage interface` should really be `Loader`, `Saver` or `LoadSaver`, following Go convention). Interfaces may be good but I also subscribe to the "Interfaces should only be used when their added value is clear" [Avoid Interface Pollution](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2016/10/avoid-interface-pollution.html)

Comment: HI, ive provide the full code which works E2E , it will be great if you can take it as an example and update.

Comment: if something is missing, please let me know

Comment: here you can see the full project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jZ3BurGyFBxsma1Mry1Gbxrke7Fw9ehv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: updated answer such that `template.go` expects a logger of type `*logrus.Logger`. To be precise, all the methods in logrus.Logger are now accessible in `template.go` (which may be what you want). If you were to simplify such that `template.go` just 'knows' one logging function, you can refactor to use that function's signature.

Comment: 1+ it will be great if you can update with the latest project, this is real working example in my context.  :)

Comment: May I suggest turning the project on g-drive into an actual github repo. I really think it would help contributors if changes could be managed under a git source control.

Comment: Yes I try it and I dont able to success to push it to github :( , something with certificate which im not sure how to solve . if you are familiar with github I think its good idea to put the project there as reference

Comment: HI Did you able to upload to github ?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out how to upload to Github. It even has a web UI and stuff.

Comment: Hi, as you requested please see the git repo that you can use to demonstrate your proposal .https://github.com/RaynDol/cli

Comment: HI, Can you please have a look at the git repo?

Comment: Hi Rayn, I created a PR on your github page. As this as become quite specific to your case, we should continue discussion there via GitHub comments.

Comment: Hi, thanks I saw your pr but not understand where is the DI , direct import is not ab

Comment: I mean not a problem (direct import)

Answer (score 5):

There are a few possibilities, each with their own tradeoffs.

1. Pass in dependencies explicitly
2. Pass in a context with all dependencies
3. Use a struct for context to methods
4. Use a package global and import

All of them have their place in different circumstances, and all have different tradeoffs:

1. This is very clear, but can get very messy and clutters your functions with lots of dependencies. It makes tests easy to mock if that is your thing.
2. This is my least favourite option, as it is seductive at first but quickly grows to a god object which mixes lots of unrelated concerns. Avoid.
3. This can be very useful in many cases, for example many people approach db access this way. Also easy to mock if required. This allows you to set/share dependencies without changing code at point of use - basically invert control in a neater way than passing in explicit parameters.
4. This has the virtue of clarity and orthogonality. It will require you to add separate setup for say tests vs production, initialising the package to the proper state prior to using it. Some dislike it for that reason.

I prefer the package global approach for something like logging, as long as a very simple signature is used. I don’t tend to test log output, or change logger often. Consider what you really need from logs, and whether it might be best just to use the built in log package, and perhaps try one of these approaches to see which suit you.

Examples in pseudo code for brevity:

```
// 1. Pass in dependencies explicitly
func MyFunc(log LoggerInterface, param, param)


// 2. Pass in a context with all dependencies

func MyFunc(c *ContextInterface, param, param)

// 3. Use a struct for context to methods

func (controller *MyController) MyFunc(param, param) {
   controller.Logger.Printf("myfunc: doing foo:%s to bar:%s",foo, bar) 
}

// 4. Use a package global and import

package log 

var DefaultLogger PrintfLogger

func Printf(format, args) {DefaultLogger.Printf(format, args)}

// usage: 

import "xxx/log"

log.Printf("myfunc: doing foo:%s to bar:%s",foo, bar)
```

I prefer this option 4 for logging and config, and even db access as it is explicit, flexible, and allows easily switching out another logger - just change the imports, no interfaces to change. The calculation on which is best depends on circumstances though - if you were writing a library for widespread use you might prefer to allow setting a logger at the struct level.

I'd usually require setup with an explicit setup on app startup, and always avoid using init functions as they are confusing and difficult to test.

Comment: Hi, thanks , two questions 1. Can you please add some example to the third option, which looks for what im looking for  ? 2. what do you mean with the `global ` , how the project structure should be used and how I share the global ? Thanks!

Comment: HI, I put a bounty , it will be great if you can add example for two of recommended  sections in your answer

Comment: I've added an example for each type. 3. Struct this is similar to having a controller for actions say which holds logger, db etc, then just use methods on that controller instead of pure functions. It just hides your dependencies and is arguably neater.  4. Package global, you set a default logger in the log package, then you can just log with simple functions as in the default log package which comes with go.

Comment: Part of your problem here stems from trying to use a third party log package, which will make its own opinionated decisions on this. That precludes option 4 for example. I'd consider whether you really need logging to be complex - having tried lots of different libraries, I've settled on something much simpler (printf style). The Go authors were right on this I think logging is not metrics, logging should not be complex. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest a simple import, my question is if my project will be on Github and i want to access from `cmd` to `internal` packages like logger, if I will have a problem ? I ask because it's under internal

Comment: You can import internal/x from anything sharing the same root package - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351387/how-to-use-internal-packages using internal is also entirely optional, and may not be suitable if you expect the packages to be generally useful (e.g. a logging package might be shared between your projects). I would avoid use of internal unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: I appreciate that you focused on trade-offs, giving the pros/cons for each approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've always explicitly passed a `*logrus.Logger` into functions (or occasionally objects) that needed it.  That avoids weird dependency cycles, makes it explicit that logging is part of the things this function does, and makes it easier to reuse the function or module elsewhere.  The initial log object is created and configured in my main function (likely after some command-line argument handling).

Comment: How, can you please provide example ? in addition in case I've one or more things to pass how would you handle it ?I dont want my functions signature will be big ...