# Module heptio/workgroup moved to projectcontour/contour/internal/workgroup

Tags: go, contour, workgroup

Module heptio/workgroup moved to projectcontour/contour/internal/workgroup. How would I use an internal package in my project? I am using go modules for dependency management.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33351387/13860

Answer (score 1):

You can't (well, unless you use a version of Go < 1.5)

https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages

> "internal" packages that may not be imported by packages outside the source subtree in which they reside.
>
> from 1.5 and onward it will be enforced for any repository.

You'll need to either find a different library that does the same thing, or copy the code into your own package.